# Return single element from SObject

Tags: soql

I have a SObject called `DDStatus__c` which has `LastUpdated__c` field (DateTime type). How can I get latest datetime using SOQL query.

Comment: Per record or overall MAX as an aggregate result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this query to get the record showing the latest datetime:

> [Select Id From DDStatus_*c Order By LastUpdated*_c DESC Limit 1]

You can add a Where clause if this is a child object and you're looking for the latest datetime for a specific parent record.

Comment: `[Select Id From DDStatus_c Order By LastUpdated_c DESC Limit 1]` is returning list. why?

Comment: Any SOQL query statement will return a list. But there are few exceptions like the **COUNT** aggregate query that returns an **integer**. You can get the first element from the list returned by the query by checking the list count.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, this line should work, as long as you are certain the record you're querying for exists. If you aren't sure it exists, you should cast the query to a list, and look for the first element in the list to get the field value from.

```
Datetime dt = [select LastUpdated__c from DDStatus__c where Id = :someId].LastUpdated__c;
```